# Include apk module as dependency in android studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I have two modules in my project:

1. app
2. app_list

Both modules have java and res. `app_list` has some activities that I want to launch in `app`.

In Eclipse, I had app_list as dependency library and I was able to launch activity of `app_list`. In Android Studio, when I added `app_list` as dependency, it says:

```
"Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Dependency NewMathBuzz:app_list:unspecified on project app resolves to an APK archive which is not supported as a compilation dependency. File: <home>/NewMathBuzz/app_list/build/outputs/apk/app_list-release-unsigned.apk
"
```

app > build.gradle is as below:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mass.mathbuzz"
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':app_list')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

app_list > build.gradle is as below:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.18'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
}
```

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: apk files can't be dependancies. You do something wrong

Comment: @Vlad then how can I do it, Basically the app_list has generic Activity I want to include in many application so I am making ad module

Comment: show your build.gradle

Comment: @VladMatvienko i just updates , could you see

Comment: ok, try changing `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` in your `app_list` `build.gradle` to  `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'`

Comment: I tried that also, so it will not include static class R.java so I will get runtime error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Everything was fine,

basically when I changed `app_list.gradle` as

`apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` to `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'` and deleted `applicationId` from `app_list.gradle`
it compiled and generated apk but I was getting runtime error that was because both app and app_list both had same resource main_activity so R.java didn't have `main_activity` res of `app_list` so it was giving illegal_parameter error . When I changed name of `main_activity` to some unique name it solved the issue

Comment: This solved it for me. In the gradle of the project I wanted to use as a library I had set it `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` and not `library'. Thanks.