# Android Studio Library project error

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, aar, library-project

I have imported a module into my project. When i rebuilt the project , AS gave me an error saying Warning:Dependency Lib:unspecified on project app resolves to an APK archive which is not supported as a compilation dependency. **I searched and changed apply plugin**: `'com.android.application'` to `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'` and also removed ApplicationId from defaultConfig. Yet i am getting this same error `"Warning:Dependency Lib:unspecified on project app resolves to an APK archive which is not supported as a compilation dependency."` Can any one help me?

Here is my gradle code:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

    android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 12
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    }

    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
    compile project(':DimenLib')
    }
```

Comment: can you post your gradle code?

Comment: @David Is this the gradle code of module or app , also the error you are getting "Warning:Dependency Lib:unspecified" shows it cannot find the lib that is why showing unspecified

Comment: as per same @Amar suggest if you developing _app_ your gradle have `apply plugin: 'com.android.application' ` else if it is `module`, your gradle have `apply plugin: 'com.android.library' `

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31787136/include-apk-module-as-dependency-in-android-studio)

Comment: @Amar ..How stupid i was. I changed apply plugin: 'com.android.library' in my app and not in module. But i have another doubt. Will library project take build??

Comment: @David, can you please be more specific what was the change you made? I changed it in build.grade(Module:app), that's the only "apply plugin" I find in the project...

Comment: @Mor Are you getting error while adding library project?

Comment: @David Yes, just like in your question. I try to add this to my project: https://github.com/ZieIony/MaterialRecents

Comment: @Mor Please check that you have apply plugin: 'com.android.library' in the build.gradle of your library project.

Comment: @Mor Is there a specific reason you want to add the project as a library. You could simply add this 'com.github.ZieIony:MaterialRecents:d2aec46f48' in your build.gradle(Module:app)

Comment: @David That's exactly what I do... and I also added maven { url "https://jitpack.io" } in the repositories, just like he says, and I get this error.

Comment: @Mor Can you post the code of you gradle file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102827/discussion-between-david-and-mor).

Answer (score 33):

> "Warning:Dependency Lib:unspecified on project app resolves to an APK archive which is not supported as a compilation dependency."

**It happens when you are trying to add a dependency which is an APK.**

Using:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

tells Gradle to build it as an application, **generating an APK**.

Using:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

**it will build as a library, generating an AAR**.

In your case, it seems that you are changing the plugin in the wrong place.
**It seems to be your main module**.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

dependencies {
    compile project(':DimenLib')
}
```

Move the `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'` in your `DimenLib`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` instead of `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'`

> apply plugin: 'com.android.application' applies the Android plugin for
>   Gradle to this build. This adds Android-specific build tasks to the
>   top-level build tasks and makes the android {...} element available to
>   specify Android-specific build options.

Have a look here

http://developer.android.com/tools/building/plugin-for-gradle.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27342458/apply-plugin-android-or-apply-plugin-com-android-application

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and that's what solved it:

1. importing the external project as explained here: 
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2D9lYuRECoI
2. In my project build.gradle file added compile project(':IMPORTED_PROJECT_NAME').
3. Only then changed in the *imported project gradle file* "apply plugin: com.android.application" to "apply plugin: com.android.library"and removed applicationId.